# How to search users more precisely using sql?

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement that searches for users and their username. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_info 
WHERE username,name LIKE '$search%' and id!='$myId' OR MATCH (name,username) AGAINST ('$search' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AND id!='$myId' 
LIMIT 10
```

What's wrong in here?
Can anyone suggest me a better and faster algorithm to search for people?

Comment: Reminder: fulltext search `(MATCH AGAINST...`) works strangely on tables with less than a few hundred rows.  Please [edit] your question to be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MySQL here to test, but the syntax `foo,bar like '...'` doesn't look right.  That probably needs to be broken out and turned into an OR.

After that, in SQL `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`.  So `A OR B AND C` actually means `A OR (B AND C)`.  Therefore your id condition doesn't do what you probably want it to.  Add parentheses.

The next thing that's questionable is how you're sticking your search and ID into the SQL.  Just sticking things into the string opens you up to SQL injection attacks, which is a common security problem.  See https://xkcd.com/327/ for an example of what an injection attack looks like in practice.  Look up "placeholders" to know how to do it better.

As for faster algorithms, you probably just need indexes.